# Using SimpleType on Element Type

Tags: xml, xsd

How can I use a SimpleType on element?
I tried changing type="" for the name of SimpleType but the validator don't read correctly the simpleTypes.

I know that I can use the restrictions on the element tag but I need do it separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer, you have to create the SimpleType before the Element:

```
<xs:simpleType name="disc">
        <xs:restriction base="digitText">
            <xs:enum value="Sony"/>
            <xs:enum value="CBS"/>
            <xs:enum value="SIRE"/>
            <xs:enum value="OTRAS"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="nombre" type="digitText"/>
```